# Why is my cookie blocked by Safari on iOS7? (iphone)

Tags: iphone, ipad, safari, ios, cookies

I own a web application dealing with a Cookie (for authentication).

On all devices (Macbook, PC, even Ipad iOS7) excepting Iphone, the whole works, meaning the cookie is well stored  on these clients.

However on the iphone iOS7, the cookie remains blocked, and thus, client can't persist his authentication.

What I do to make it work is to authorize ALL cookies in the Iphone's Safari's settings.

My question is: Is there a way to avoid this blocking? Maybe providing the Cookie with HTTPS only?

Comment: Did you check the privacy settings on the iPhone? Does it happen on just one device or did you test it on several? Is the cookie from the same domain as the application that it is reading it?

Comment: @Matteo I have this issue on two smartphones, one Android (samsung S1, older) and one Iphone 4s. On ipad, as I wrote, the whole works. Yes, my cookie comes from the same domain.